Irreducibility of $x^5-e^{10}$ in $Q(e^5)$
I try to solve this problem from Fraleigh algebra book (Problem 24.b Section 29) which asks us to find a subfield $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $e^2$ is algebraic of degree 5 over $E$. The subfield $E$ that I found is $Q(e^5)$ and the corresponding polynomial is $p(x)=x^5-e^{10}$. The only problem that I face is to prove whether this polynomial is irreducible in $Q(e^5)$. I know that this polynomial has only one real root, $e^2$, since it is an ascending polynomial, So it can not be split into the product of $2$ polynomials of degree $4$ and $1$ in $Q(e^5)$ because it can be proved $e^2\notin Q(e^5)$. So the only thing remaining to prove is whether $x^5-e^{10}$ can be split into the product of $2$ polynomials of degree 3 and 2. Eisenstein criterion can not be used because $p(x)\notin \mathbb{Z}[X]$. The only method that comes to my mind is to assume there are indeed $2$ polynomials $t(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $r(x)=dx^3+ex^2+fx+g$, such that $p(x)=t(x)r(x)$ and I reached to a system of equations that I need to solve in $Q(e^5)$ which I do not think It can be easily proved it does not have an answer in $Q(e^5)$.
Is there any straightforward way to prove the irreducibility of $x^5-e^{10}$ in $Q(e^5)$?

Note that the elements $x, e^5$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ (follows easily from the fact that $e^5$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$), and hence we have a natural isomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(e^5)[x]\cong\mathbb{Q}(y)[x]$ that sends $e^5\to y$. Isomorphism clearly preserves irreducibility, and so your question is equivalent to whether the bivariate polynomial $x^5-y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(y)[x]$. Using Gauss' lemma, this is equivalent to the question whether it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(x)[y]$. But now this is a polynomial of degree $2$ over a field, and so it is reducible if and only if it has a root in the field. But it is easy to see that there is no $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}(x)$ that satisfies $f(x)^2=x^5$.

I do not understand this part where you used Gauss's Lemma. After some searches, I do believe you used the generalization of Gauss's lemma, which states that "Suppose R is a GCD domain (e.g., a unique factorization domain) with the field of fractions F . Then a non-constant polynomial f in R [ x ] is irreducible if and only if it is irreducible in F [ x ] and the gcd of the coefficients of f is 1. " So if I'm not wrong, here R is Q(y) and F is Q(x)?

@M.Arya Gauss' lemma works in any UFD domain (maybe even GCD), just like in $\mathbb{Z}$. If $R$ is UFD and $F$ is its field of fractions then a monic polynomial $f\in R[x]$ is irreducible in $R[x]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $F[x]$. So here I used it twice. First time with $R=\mathbb{Q}(y)$. The polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(y)[x]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[y][x]\cong\mathbb{Q}[y,x]\cong\mathbb{Q}[x][y]$. And now applying the lemma again on $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]$, iff irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(x)[y]$.
